# Getting syntax error while running pyspark sql command

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql

```
afer_can_normalized_Data=sql.get_df("select * from form26AS.console_report where active=1 and is_cancelled=0 and is_normalized=1 and assessment_year=%d and company_code='%s' and company_pan='%s' and company_tan='%s' and batch_upload_id='%s'" % (assessmentYear,company_code,company_pan,company_tan,id1))
```

Getting this below error while executing the above SQL statement:

com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'select'.

Comment: Does the schema and table exist? What result do you get without parameters:  `afer_can_normalized_Data=sql.get_df("select * from form26AS.console_report " ) ` ?

Comment: @Kendle Yes, schema is present and I've given the parameters in  code. scroll right to  check it pls

Comment: I'm suggesting that you try without the where clause and the parameters to be sure that the table name is correct and all the connection parameters are working.  That will guide you where to look for the problem.

Comment: @Kendle It worked by using the below command `
afer_can_normalized_Data=sql.get_df('''(select * from form26AS.console_report where active=1 and is_cancelled=0 and is_normalized=1 and assessment_year=%d and company_code='%s' and company_pan='%s' and company_tan='%s' and batch_upload_id='%s') as temp''' %(assessmentYear,company_code,company_pan,company_tan,id1)) 
`